# ServiceStack NHibernate and Ninject in Self Hosting App (Request Context)

Tags: nhibernate, request, ninject, servicestack

I have a self hosted ServiceStack application, and I try to build ISession per request. I suppose the following will work:

```
Bind<ISession>()
  .ToMethod(NapraviSesiju)
  .InNamedScope(ControllerScope)
  .InScope(s => ReuseScope.Request)
  .OnActivation(s => s.BeginTransaction())
  .OnDeactivation(s =>
{
  if (!s.Transaction.IsActive) return;
  try
  {
    s.Transaction.Commit();
  }
    catch (Exception e)
  {
    s.Transaction.Rollback();
  }
});

private ISession NapraviSesiju(IContext kontekst)
{
  var sesija = kontekst.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession();
  return sesija;
}
```

This works, but request deactivation is not instant (it happens after 30 seconds, or 1 minute, and some requests don't deactivate at all).

Can someone please tell me the correct way to handle NHibernate Sessions this way?

**UPDATE**

Can I use this then:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
{
    private IKernel _jezgro;

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        _jezgro = new StandardKernel(new NHibernateModul());
        container.Adapter = new NinjectIocAdapter(_jezgro);
    }

    public override void Release(object instance)
    {
        _jezgro.Release(((IHasSession)instance).Sesija);    //Release Sesija from SomeServis object below
    }
}

public class SomeServis : RestServiceBase<Some>, IHasSession    //implements NHibernate Session
{
    public ISession Sesija { get; set; }    //IHasSession implementation. Injected by Ninject.
}

Bind<ISession>()
.ToMethod(NapraviSesiju)
.InScope(s => ReuseScope.Request)   //reuse per request scope. Is this really needed, since release is happening at Release in AppHost?
.OnActivation(s => s.BeginTransaction())
.OnDeactivation(s =>
{
    if (!s.Transaction.IsActive) return;
    try
    {
        s.Transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        s.Transaction.Rollback();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom of the [IOC Container wiki page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container) explains the `Release` behavior of IOC resources. The easiest way to handle disposed resources is to implement the `IRelease` method and delegate the Released instances back into Ninject, e.g:

```
public class NinjectIocAdapter : IContainerAdapter, IRelease
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    //...

    public void Release(object instance)
    {
        this.kernel.Release(instance);
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't find IRelease interface. Anyway, I can put Release method on AppHost, and instance object is RestServiceBase type. I don't need to release this but ISession from NHibernate. Isession is property of Service and when service is released it is not destructed (NInject OnDeactivation method is not called).